# Compare two hashsets?

Tags: c#

I have two hashsets like this:

```
HashSet<string> log1 = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines("log1.txt"));
HashSet<string> log2 = searcher(term);
```

How would I compare the two?

I want to make sure that `log2` does not contain any entries from `log1`. In other words, I want to remove all(if any), items that `log1` has inside `log2`.

Comment: Step through each element in log1 and compare them to each of the elements in log2, that's how I would do it. Although I'm not sure how you would access individual elements. I'm guessing you might be able to construct a foreach (string s in log1) for it? Note: I've never used the HashSet type, and I'm guessing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To remove all items from `log2` that are in `log1`, you can use the [HashSet<T>.ExceptWith Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx):

```
log2.ExceptWith(log1);
```

Alternatively, you can create a new [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504) without modifying the two original sets using the [Enumerable.Except Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
HashSet<string> log3 = new HashSet<string>(log2.Except(log1));
```

Answer (score 7):

Using LINQ:

```
log1.Intersect(log2).Any()
```

See [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) and [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - `Any()` is better.

Comment: @RoyiNamir If you need to check if there are any coins in a jar youdont have to count, rather you check if there exist any?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the `ExceptWith` function?

> Removes all elements in the specified collection from the current HashSet object.