# How to find Complement of two HashSets

Tags: c#, linq

I have two HashSets – setA and setB.

1. How can we find the complement of setA and setB?
2. Is the code for intersection the best way to find intersection?

**CODE**

```
 string stringA = "A,B,A,A";
 string stringB = "C,A,B,D";

 HashSet<string> setA = new HashSet<string>(stringA.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()));
 HashSet<string> setB = new HashSet<string>(stringB.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()));

 //Intersection - Present in A and B
 HashSet<string> intersectedSet = new HashSet<string>( setA.Intersect(setB));

 //Complemenet - Present in A; but not present in B
```

**UPDATE**:

Use `OrdianlIgnoreCase` for ignoring case sensitvity   [How to use HashSet<string>.Contains() method in case -insensitive mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667635/how-to-use-hashsetstring-contains-method-in-case-insensitive-mode)

**REFERENCE**:

1. [What is the difference between HashSet<T> and List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391738/what-is-the-difference-between-hashsett-and-listt-in-c)
2. [Intersection of multiple lists with IEnumerable.Intersect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect)
3. [Comparing two hashsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704812/comparing-two-hashsets)
4. [Compare two hashsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635923/compare-two-hashsets)
5. [Quickest way to find the complement of two collections in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193778/quickest-way-to-find-the-complement-of-two-collections-in-c-sharp)

Comment: _"How can we find the complement of setA and setB?"_ Isn't it just `setA.Except(setB)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - How can we find the complement of setA and setB?

Use [`HashSet<T>.Except Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb908036%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
//Complemenet - Present in A; but not present in B
HashSet<string> ComplemenetSet = new HashSet<string>(setA.Except(setB));
```

try it with following string.

```
string stringA = "A,B,A,E";
string stringB = "C,A,B,D";
```

ComplementSet will contain `E`

> 2 - Is the code for intersection the best way to find intersection?

Probably, YES

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Except` to get the complement of A or B.  To get a symmetric complement, use `SymmetricExceptWith`.

```
setA.SymmetricExceptWith(setB);
```

Note that this *modifies* `setA`.  To get the intersection, there are two methods: `Intersect`, which creates a new `HashSet`, and `IntersectWith`, which modifies the first:

```
// setA and setB unchanged
HashSet<string> intersection = setA.Intersect(setB);

// setA gets modified and holds the result
setA.IntersectWith(setB);
```